# insert image into database with ajax using formData

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having some difficulties with uploading an image from an html form. the form should be able to send the image name with other data to php page.

I used formData  instead of serialized function, since it can't handle files data.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url:"includes/widgets/insert.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);

        },

    });

    return false;
});
```

html form

```
 <form id="insert_post" action="includes/widgets/insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >


         <div class="row">
             <div class="medium-6 columns">
                 <label>First name
                     <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" contenteditable>
                 </label>
             </div>
             <div class="medium-6 columns">
                 <label>Last name
                     <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" contenteditable>
                 </label>
             </div>

             <div class="medium-12 columns">
                 <label>Last name
                 <input  type="file" name="file" id="image" multiple contenteditable>
                 </label>
             </div>
             </div>
              <button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="button btn btn-xs btn-success" >Submit</button>


     </form>

php page

<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "myaddboard");

echo $_POST['first_name'];
echo $_POST['last_name'];


echo $image = $_FILES['file']['name'];
echo $image_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
/*
if(empty($image)){
    echo 'error';
}

move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"img/$image");
  //$sql = "INSERT INTO posts(post_content, post_author) VALUES('".$_POST["first_name"]."', '".$_POST["last_name"]."')";

if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))
{
    echo 'Data Inserted';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
*/
?>
```

The php form is just to test if the ajax send the data correctly.

When I click on the button I always get errors that the php variables is not defined

The errors i get each time I submit the form

```
undefined index: frist_name in c:xampp\htdocs\unv\includes\widgets\insert.php on line 4
undefined index: last_name in c:xampp\htdocs\unv\includes\widgets\insert.php on line 5
undefined index: file in c:xampp\htdocs\unv\includes\widgets\insert.php on line 8
undefined index: file in c:xampp\htdocs\unv\includes\widgets\insert.php on line 9
```

what should I do to make the ajax send the data to the php page ?

Comment: What is the error .. please post

Comment: I updated  question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work because of how your selector is created.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
```

In the above scenario, `$(this)[0]` is getting you the raw HTML interpretation of the `button`.

What you actually want is to change your button to a `submit` type, capture the `form submit event`, and then process your request.

```
button type="submit" <-- change

$(document).on('submit', '#insert_post', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //stop default form submission

    //do the rest of your stuff here
});
```

Now `$(this)[0]` is actually the `form` and not the `button`.

Comment: mm  it work like a charm thank you very much.  Last time I tried the submit type,  it always direct me to action page so I used button instead. but it working now as it should. Thanks again .